# SQL Server parameterized query - explicit SQL statements vs sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

Is there a performance (or any other) difference between using explicit SQL statements vs `sp_executesql`, for a parameterised query?

E.g. SQL statements:

```
DECLARE @objectName SYSNAME, @objectType CHAR(2)

SELECT @objectName = N'sysrscols', @objectType='s' 

SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE [name] = @objectName AND [type] = @objectType
```

And the same via `sp_executesql`:

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql
   N'select * from sys.objects where [name] = @objectName and [type] = @objectType',
       N'@objectName SYSNAME, @objectType CHAR(2)',
       @objectName = N'sysrscols', @objectType = 's'
```

Why does Entity Framework use `sp_executesql`? When using SQL Server Profiler to see the queries it generates, it would be so much easier to read them if they were just SQL statements.

Comment: This is for performance reason. `sp_executesql` statement (1st parameter) is compiled and can be reused if only parameter values change.

Comment: "it would be so much easier to read them if they were just SQL statements" If you want to see the SQL EF generates, I recommend [using EFs `Database.Log`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nuance is the first query is not parameterized. It is a batch of SQL statements where the local variable is used in the query. This batch of statements is sent to SQL Server as a batch request without parameters where it is compiled and executed. You can see from a trace (Profiler or Extended Events) that the event type is `*batch*` rather than `*rpc*`.

When SqlClient applications (including EF-generated SQL statements) use parameterized queries (by adding parameters to `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection and parameter names in the SQL statement), the request sent to SQL Server as an RPC (remote procedure call) request where parameter values are defined and passed separately from the SQL Statement itself. The trace event will show `rpc_*` instead of `sql_batch_*`. The SqlClient API uses an sp_executesql for this.

Parameterized queries have many benefits, whether generated by EF or in code directly. These include:

- are more secure, preventing SQL injection
- eliminate the need to escape quotes within strings
- avoid the need to format date string literals in a particular way
- do not require decimal separators
- improve performance by promoting plan cache reuse

I'll add that the text you see in the Profiler trace of the RPC call is just a reverse engineering of the underlying TDS protocol request. If you run a network trace, you will see no reference to `sp_executesql` statement you see in the trace. But the main point with parameterized queries is that the parameter values are passed separately to SQL Server in native format.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is entirely in how SQL server will optimize the execution if only parameters change. If you use a normal statement like this, the statement will be compiled and executed as is every time you run it. If you use `sp_executesql` and run it many different times with only other parameters, SQL server is "likely" to reuse the execution plan, saving on performance:

> sp_executesql can be used instead of stored procedures to execute a
>   Transact-SQL statement many times when the change in parameter values
>   to the statement is the only variation. Because the Transact-SQL
>   statement itself remains constant and only the parameter values
>   change, the SQL Server query optimizer is likely to reuse the
>   execution plan it generates for the first execution.

[(source on MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks @Magisch, but won't SQL server cache execution plans for ALL paremeterised queries, whether they are inside sp_executesql or just plain sql statement?

Comment: Actually it just advises that this is better then straight up executing a parameterized SQL string each time. Seems like SPs are also cached in this way @Andrew

Comment: @Magisch Can you quote the exact phrase(s) that state your assertion? AFAICT, if the SQL is exactly the same as a previously executed on (character per character), the execution plan that was previously generated will be reused.

Comment: @TT. This will not be the case though if you execute a full sql string with different parameters, right?

Comment: @Magisch AFAICT, indeed.

Comment: @TT. seems to me the advantage of sp_executesql is to divorce the parameters from the query string, allowing the execution plan to be cached if you need to run it several times with only different parameters, unlike a normal execute(string) where the parameters are part of the query string

Comment: @Magisch Sure, but it can be a disadvantage in certain scenarios as well: parameter sniffing problems, where the execution plan is suboptimal for different parameters.

Comment: @TT. you're right of course, but I'd assume that if you can anticipate execution plan inaccuracies for specific parameter ranges and care enough about that for it to make a difference, you'd use a different query structure alltogether for the offending cases.

Comment: @TT, Magisch So there's no doubt that execution plans of stored procs and sp_executesql statements are cached. But what about parameterised queries? Like TT said, "if the SQL is exactly the same as a previously executed on (character per character), the execution plan that was previously generated will be reused". I think this is correct. This means the two examples in my question will have the same cache efficiency, and my question still stands: why does Entity Framework use the less readable format?

Comment: @Andrew Where did you get that? In your first example, that is a whole SQL statement. If you change its parameters, you change the statement, since the parameters are _part_ of the statement. If you use sp_executesql, the parameters are supplied seperately and not part of the statement, allowing the statement execution plan (that does not include the parameters) to be reused.